# baking normals Isn't baking the normal texture of the higher poly mesh

Tags: baking, normal-map

I'm working on a cloth and im trying to optimize it using bake, but I'm getting a problem when I bake the normals, where the blender is only considering the geometry of the higher poly mesh and not the normal texture that is on it.
For example, the left object normals are without the leather normals after I bake it:
[image: 1]
I did it before and it worked fine on the skirt, but I don't know what I did to make it work
[image: 2]
is there something that i'm missing?

UPDATE: I found out that it's baking on dev 2.79.6 but not in 2.79b. is this the problem or do I need to change something in 2.79b in order to work

Comment: Sounds like "The yellow node problem" ) On your shot I do not see that on baking there is a dedicated target image node, that is ONLY selected while you hit the bake button. Maybe this will work things out?

Comment: yeah, I selected the node before baking, but this is not the problem, I need to go to the dev 1.79.6 to bake the normals as I said before

Comment: Well it should be a bug. If you have the version that works, the only way is to use this particular one. For example I've recently found that since the 2.72 the defocus node works only in 64 bit or linux versions, but not in win32 builds. What a pleasant surprise! :-) Now I render scenes with this node in linux or in amd64. :-/

Comment: yeah, probably. The most annoying part is that in 2.79.6 I cant bake the difuse textures because there is a bug with the cuda cores, so I need to go back to 2.79b just to bake the textures.